# Spring react process more mono in mono

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I have a method like:

```
public Mono<Double> calculate(OperandDto dto) {
    Mono<Double> dbResult1Mono = mongoReactRepo.findByMyLogic(dto);
    Mono<Double> dbResult2Mono = mongoReactRepo.findByMyOtherLogic(dto);

    // ? Multiply these results (dbResult1Mono * dbResult2Mono), and return with Mono<Double> ?
}
```

And I would like to multiply 2 Mono objects' result and return a new Mono one in a reactive way.

Can anybody help me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flux.combineLatest()`:

```
    Mono<Double> dbResult1Mono = Mono.just(2d);
    Mono<Double> dbResult2Mono = Mono.just(5d);

   return Flux.combineLatest(dbResult1Mono, dbResult2Mono, (r1, r2) -> r1 * r2).next();
```

Comment: It seems like good, thanks, 

Is there any way to use Mono like in nodejs:

myVar = await Mono.just(2d);

Or If I had 1 mono, how to process the result, and return with a new Mono ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with node.js.
About processing result of a mono and getting resulted mono - you can take a look 
on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156111/2304545

It is pretty similar to work with Java streams. You create pipeline of the operations like map, flatMap, zip, ... and receive resulted Mono or Flux that will be handled by Reactor when somebody subscribes on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful. 

Actually I have a very simple method, I would like to test how the reactive way is faster then normal way. In my test it seems the reactive way is 2x times slower then blocking way. Can u help me, what is the wrong with my code? I would pay your time ... Thanks a lot, it is important for me :)

Comment: this is my code: https://github.com/loxon-lab/reactive-programming/blob/master/reactiveSpringMeetup/src/main/java/eu/loxon/reactiveSpringMeetup/service/CalculationService.java

and the calculateStream method is the main method.

Comment: Perhaps the biggest problem is in this line: calculateReactive(e).block(); Don't use block() as it is synchronous method. I'd suggest to rewrite that block using flatMap()
Try this:
alcObj.flatMap(e -> calculateReactive(e)) instead of  calcObj.map(e -> {
   return calculateReactive(e).block();
  });

Comment: Thanks, the performance getting much better, but I think I lost somewhere the reactive way, maybe in calculateStream method, because after 500 parallel requests I got this mongo exception: Too many threads are already waiting for a connection. "Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded".
I think the reactive calculation is not good, because I would not have to get it...