# Spring boot 2.0.0 reactive mongodb cannot add to collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

my use case is quite simple:

I store Persons and a Set of notes for each person, which I expect to look like this in mongoldb:

```
{
    :id: ObjectId(...)
    "name": "Bob"
    "notes": ["nice", "tall"]
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
@Document
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Person {
    @Id
    ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    @Singular
    private Set<String> notes;

}
```

If I use a standard Repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, ObjectId> {
    Mono<Person> findByName(String name);
}
```

And try to add a new Note like this:

```
personRepository.findByName(name)
.doOnSuccess( person -> personRepository
    .save(person.toBuilder().note(newNote).build())
    .block() //or subscribe(), doOnSuccess(), doOnError() does not matter
);
```

When retrieving the person by name from the database again after this, the note is not present.

It also does not work with without using the builder:

```
person.getNotes().add(newNote)
personRepository.save(person)
```

how is this done correctly?

edit:

It works the other way round, if I insert notes into the database, they are loaded correctly.

Comment: Please see my answer about reactive Mongo repository: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49156111/2304545

Comment: Perhaps the cause of the described issue is that nobody subscribed to the Mono returned by: personRepository.save(person)

Comment: the call to block() should cause it to execute I think?

Comment: Yes, it is blocking method. The thread that executed this method will be blocked and will wait the result of Mono.

Comment: please answer so i can close this